# contour approximation in opencv python is giving wrong result everytime

Tags: python, opencv, contour, approximation

I am an absolute beginner in image processing.I want to detect a nested shape among various different edges.from my program I have successfully detected my expected contour through hierarchy relation.but my problem arises when I am going to detect the shape.for contour approximation, I am using `cv2.approxpolyDP()` method/function on my desired contour using its index number.but every time it is resulting in the same output, which is "1".I don't know where I am mistaking.please have a look and suggest me some.The code is given below and the images to be detected is also given in those links. please help me...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
maxx=0
original_color=cv2.imread("tri.jpg",1)
original=cv2.cvtColor(original_color,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv2.imshow("original",original)
blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(original,(5,5),0)
ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(blur,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh,100,200)
image,contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(edges.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print len(contours)
##for c in range(0,len(hierarchy)) :
##    a=zip(hierarchy[c],contours[c])

for i in range(0,len(hierarchy[0])):
    if hierarchy[0][i][2]>=maxx :
         if(hierarchy[0][i][3]==(hierarchy[0][i][2]-2)):
             maxx=hierarchy[0][i][2]
             index=i
cnt=contours[index]
for c in cnt :
    peri=cv2.arcLength(c,True)
    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(c,0.04*peri,True)
print hierarchy
print maxx
print len(approx)

cv2.drawContours(original_color,contours,index,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow("Show",original_color)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Before Detection**

[image: before detection]

**Succesfully Detected**

[image: successfully detected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of findContours is a list of list of points, this means that the problem is here:

```
cnt=contours[index]
for c in cnt :
    peri=cv2.arcLength(c,True)
    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(c,0.04*peri,True)
```

Here you select a contour(list of pointS) and then loop for each point and do the approxPolyDP with only 1 point. You should do it to the contour. So, if you want it to do it for the selected contour, you should do:

```
cnt=contours[index]
peri=cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.04*peri,True)
```

If you want to do it for each contour then do like this (keeping the print inside the loop, if not it will show only the last one):

```
for c in contours:
    peri=cv2.arcLength(c,True)
    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(c,0.04*peri,True)
    print len(approx)
```